# Understanding associative operations

Tags: associativity

If something is associative, then for example $(x + y) + z = x + (y + z)$ is true. I also know that in general subtraction is not an associative operation, but what if subtraction is applied to $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Is subtraction an associative operation then? Since $0-0=0-0$.

Comment: A single example is not enough.  Yes, subtraction is associative on the set containing {0} and *nothing* else.  But that is a  (literally) trivial case.  To state that "subtraction is associative" then it is associative for *ALL* $a,b,c$ and not just one special case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Subtraction is associative on $\{0\}$..

But that is a trivial case.  Less trivial subtraction is also associative on $\mathbb  Z_2 =\{0,1| 0+1=1+0 = 1; 0+0 = 0; 1+1 = 0\}$ (because $1 = -1$).

But for any group with at least three elements it is not:

I think.

Comment: Subtraction is associative in all fields of characteristic $2.$

Comment: Okay.  Which the real number with the usual addition and multiplication is not.